# Calculating the distribution of the random variable Y at the output

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, entropy

**Given**

The random variable X at the entrance to the transmission path is sufficient for the following distribution.

$X = P(x)$

$x_1=0.1$ $x_2=0.2$ $x_3=0.3$ $x_4=0.4$

The random variable $Y$ at the output of the transmission link only takes three values. The transfer matrix $T$ with $p_{i}^{j} = P(Y = y_j | X = x_i)$ is

$T = (p_{i}^{j})= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.50 & 0 & 0.50 \\
0.20 & 0.40 & 0.40 \\
0.50 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0 & 0.50 & 0.50
\end{pmatrix}$

**Task**

Calculate the distribution of the random variable Y at the output.

**Approach**

I know that $P(y_j | 0.1) = 0.50$ $P(y_j | 0.2) = 0.20$... for the first column but I don't know how to solve the equation that the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Did you mean the *probability masses* of $X$ are given by 0.1,0.2, etc. ?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio exactly. I didn't found a good table where I can present this better here on this StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a matrix of conditional probabilities, with the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of $T$ corresponding to $P(Y=y_j|X=x_i)$. To find the marginal distribution of $Y$, use the law of total probability:

$$P(Y=y_j)=\sum_{i=1}^4 P(Y=y_j|X=x_i)P(X=x_i)$$

Note: If $p$ represents a $1\times 4$ row vector summarizing the probability masses of $X$, then $pT$ is a $1\times 3$ row vector summarizing the masses of $Y$.

Comment: Is $P(Y = x_j|X = x_i) = \frac{y_j}{x_i} $ or how to calculate this?

Comment: You don't have to calculate the conditional probability; as you mention in your question, it is an entry in the matrix $T$.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4\end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}
0.50 & 0 & 0.50 \\
0.20 & 0.40 & 0.40 \\
0.50 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0 & 0.50 & 0.50
\end{pmatrix}$ should give me a $1 \times 3$ row vector summarizing the masses of $Y$ you are saying?

Comment: @MaxHager exactly